# Oracle SQLPlus how to not round number on select

Tags: oracle, numbers, sqlplus

When I request my Oracle database with sqlplus, all numbers are rounded. For example:

```
-1.238E+10 instead of -12381762117.99
```

How can I get the right value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use COLUMN FORMAT command:

```
SQL> select -12381762117.99 from dual;

-12381762117.99                                                                 
---------------                                                                 
     -1,238E+10                                                                 

SQL> col x format 99999999999999999.99
SQL> select -12381762117.99 x from dual;

                    X                                                         
---------------------                                                         
      -12381762117.99
```

Comment: Or you can simply increase `numwidth` value, if you do not want to bother yourself with column format each time.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Do you have an idea on how I can implement this in a Python script requesting by odbc ?

Comment: @user When you use ODBC you will get the number as a floating point number, so you won't have that problem.